# Processing dropdown selectbox options with ajax autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm  not sure on how to do all of this, i've seen ajax / jquery autocomplete scripts but I want to query two different tables depending upon what is selected from a dropdown box. Is something like this even possible or would have have to combine the two databases into one

This is what I want to do.

Country: US , Canada (dropdown selectbox)

If user select US Then query search_us table for the autocomplete on ...

City or Zip/Postal: [      ] (textbox)

Else If Canada is selected Then query search_ca table for autocomplete on ...

City or Zip/Postal: [      ] (textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just attach a query param to the url of the php that sets the table. Then run the autocomplete as usual. For example, this may be your set up:

```
$("#your_textbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === "Canada"){
        $("#zip_code").autocomplete("option", "source", "your_script.php?country=CA");
    } else {
        $("#zip_code").autocomplete("option", "source", "your_script.php?country=US");
    }   
});

$("#zip_code").autocomplete({
    source: "",
    minLength: 2
  });
```

Then in your php script you pick up the param:

```
$ac_country = $_GET['country'];
```

Comment: which ajax autocomplete would you recommend using to work best with your example?

Comment: @acctman my example uses the jquery ui autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: would you happen to have a working example. Been trying all day and can't get it to work

Comment: @acctman Here is a [tutorial](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/05/29/using-jquery-autocomplete-to-populate-another-autocomplete-asp-net-coldfusion-and-php-examples/) and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/WLypP/)

Comment: thanks, i've been setting this up all wrong. now i see my mistakes after going over the tutorial and fiddle link

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is ask JQuery to [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) the selected item of your dropdown `onChange()`. This should then send a request to your PHP script.

Your script would look at the posted value and see if it's either US or Canada.

Depending on which is selected, it can then run those queries in your databases and return an appropriate response in JSON format.

You can then capture that response (a list of autocompletes) and apply that to your textbox using whatever UI component you are using for autocomplete.